# How to determine LocalDb instance name in SQL script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, localdb

For a non-LocalDb SQL Server, I can `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')` to get the name of the server and the instance that I'm running on. For a LocalDb server, however, I get `SERVERNAME\LOCALDB#SOMEHASH`. How can I get the local instance name?

**SOLUTION:**

The solution for getting the instance, working on both LocalDB and "normal" SQL Server instances:

```
DECLARE @serverName NVARCHAR(151)
IF SERVERPROPERTY('IsLocalDb') = 1
    SELECT @serverName = 'np:\\.\pipe\' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')) + '\tsql\query'
ELSE
    SELECT @serverName = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName'))
```

Some background that I should have mentioned in the original question: We have a configuration database for our application. Among other things, it stores connection strings. For developer machines and integration tests, we want to be able to generate a database with a script, and have the connection string refer to the local instance. Thus, I need to have a working connection string (which `LOCALDB#SOMEHASH` is not). Since there is some spread in edition of database server, I needed something that could handle both cases.

Comment: Why is SERVERNAME\LOCALDB#SOMEHASH unacceptable?

Comment: @RaySaltrelli: Because it cannot be used to connect to the localdb from code in my tests

Comment: Select @@Servername isn't what you need?

Comment: @granadaCoder: It is the same as `SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')`

Comment: Sorry.  I think I goofed.  Can you run a Select @@VERSION and post?

Comment: does it have to be dynamic? or is your server/instance name static?

Comment: I needed a solution for running bcp from a stored proc. I'm building the stored proc on my localdb and will deploy to sql server 2016. But I need to deploy via automated script. So I cannot edit the proc beforehand. The @@servername on localdb returns a name that bcp does not accept. But, the above solution worked for me in dev and qa/prod. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('InstanceName')
```

**EDIT**

from [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx)

Connecting to a Shared Instance of LocalDB

To connect to a shared instance of LocalDB add .\ (dot + backslash) to the connection string to reference the namespace reserved for shared instances. For example, to connect to a shared instance of LocalDB named AppData use a connection string such as (localdb).\AppData as part of the connection string. A user connecting to a shared instance of LocalDB that they do not own must have a Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication login.

**and**

If your application uses a version of .NET before 4.0.2 you must connect directly to the named pipe of the LocalDB. The Instance pipe name value is the named pipe that the instance of LocalDB is listening on. The portion of the Instance pipe name after LOCALDB# will change each time the instance of LocalDB is started. To connect to the instance of LocalDB by using SQL Server Management Studio, type the Instance pipe name in the Server name box of the Connect to Database Engine dialog box. From your custom program you can establish connection to the instance of LocalDB using a connection string similar to `SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#F365A78E\tsql\query");`

Comment: That returns the `LOCALDB#SOMEHASH` part, unfortunately.

Comment: are you familiar with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx)

Comment: Yes, and thus my question. In my quick test at least, I could not connect to `(localdb)\LOCALDB#SOMEHASH`. Should I expect to be able to?

Comment: @carlpett and one more time)

Comment: Excellent! Wasn't aware of being able to use the named pipe in a connection string. Updated question with solution